# How to log arbitrary request headers in Flask?

Tags: python, http, flask, logging

How do you log headers such as `X-Request-ID` (or `X-Amzn-Trace-Id`) in Flask v3?

(Apparently in version 1 Flask needed an extension to provide this functionality but [that project](https://github.com/Workable/flask-log-request-id) was orphaned and is no longer compatible.)

Comment: `print(request.headers)` doesn't help…?

Answer (score 0):

As already noted (h/t deceze) the flask API passes a request object into your app methods, including (as an attribute) a dictionary of the headers.

The flask docs also [have a section](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/logging/#injecting-request-information) on customising the default logging behaviour to inject request metadata.

For example:

```py
import flask.logging, logging

class RequestFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.foo = flask.request.headers.get('x-request-id', None) \
                     if flask.has_request_context() else None
        return super().format(record)

formatter = RequestFormatter("[%(asctime)s] %(foo)")

flask.logging.default_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```